# PHP - change first directory in url and keep remaining directories

Tags: php

I have two language website, English and Russian;

english version: www.example.com
russian version: www.example.com/ru/

Looking at the example below, how can I direct PHP to add ru directory after my domain and keep the remaining url of the current page as is
so forexample, if the current page url is: http://example.com/newyork/car/

then I want to change a link to: http://example.com/ru/newyork/car/">Russian

Comment: User relative references and rewriting on http level.

Comment: can you please elaborate arkascha, am a newbie in php

Comment: This is nothing php specific, it is how the web and http work. If you use relative references then the base url of your pages can be whatever they are, the references keep it. Then, on http level, so inside your http server (not inside php but before), you use the servers rewriting capabilities to detect if the `ru` exists in the request. If so you remove it and maybe set an environment variable indicating the language or you add it is a request parameter. Or you don't put the `ru` in the url at all (does not belong there in my eyes) but keep the language in the server side session only.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this to fetch the requested url..

```
$return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //return url
```

> if need to provide back link to original page use

```
//redirect back to original page
<a href="<?php echo $return_url; ?"> Back </a>
```

Comment: yes but how can I add the directory ru after my domain and before the other folders